# Return list from resolve

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am trying to return a  data list from a resolve then access that list in my controller after. Resolve is suppose to fire before the controller is loaded, but it seems to be the opposite.

**dbdata.getlist** is an api call using $http.get which returns a list.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        resolve : {
            listdata: ['$q','dbdata',function ($q,dbdata) {
                dbdata.getlist(function(data){
                     return data;
                });
            }]
        },
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })

....
}
```

---

```
angular.module('amebaTvApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope,listdata) {
      $scope.list = listdata;
...
  }]);
```

---

Suggested edits:

I get **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined** when I try the code below

```
 listdata: ['$q','dbdata',function ($q,dbdata) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                dbdata.getFeatures(function(data){
                     deferred.resolve(data);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }]
```

....

```
 listdata.then( function(data) { 
            $scope.list = data;  
      });
```

lisdata seems to be undefined when the controller loads that's why I was getting the error :  **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

If I access listdata like so : $route.current.locals.listdata then it works.

Comment: Check promise in controller... listdata.then(
          function(data) {
              $scope.list = data;
          })

Comment: @Asik I'm returning a list so the function 'then' can not be applied to it.

Comment: @Fabii you are returning a list from your callback function **not** from your resolve function. The idea of `resolve` is to return a promise and when that promise is resolved it will allow the route to change and injecting that value from the promise into your new controller.

Comment: Make getList return a promise then return it with `then` chaining

Comment: @Brocco Is my suggested edit above correct ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Is my suggested edit above correct ? Example please .

Answer (score 0):

Access listdata via $route.current.locals.listdata seems to have done the trick. Whether this is the correct way I am not too sure .  Any feedback would be great .